# How to transfer different cryptocoins from one daemon to another

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, client, trading, currencies

How to transfer different cryptocoins from one daemon to another. I want to send currency from dogecoin to bitcoin, I think trading engine do such process. Can I implement such process across local daemons

Answer (score 5):

How do you transfer your potatos into rice?

You go to market, find somebody who wants to "transfer" his rice into potatos and exchange it with him. There's no direct way of transfering one commodity into another (except perhaps alchemy).

So no, you can't transfer cryptocoins across different cryptocoin daemons, that's impossible.

But there's plenty markets with crypto coins out there, try googling **cryptocurrency exchange**.